# Unable to `syscall.Kill()` a daemonized Go process

Tags: go, signals, daemon, sigkill

I made program in Go that kills a process with `syscall.Kill()`

But if I daeminze that process with `fork()` + `setsid()` then `syscall.Kill()` does not kill that process.

If I use shell `kill` then I'm able to kill that process in both cases.

I tried different signals: `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL` buthey do not kill the daemon.

Comment: Are you checking the error from the syscall? syscall.Kill should work just like kill from the commandline

Comment: Are you positive you're sending your signal to the right PID?

Comment: PID is correct. It  is automatically taken from `run.pid` file and `PID` is printed on screen. So `PID` is correct.

Comment: `syscall.Kill` returns `nil`

Comment: What is _run.pid_? If `syscall.Kill()` is working, and then adding _fork()_ makes it stop working, then it sounds plausible that you're killing the initial process, and not the child one. Did you collate PID not only with _run.pid_, but also the output of ps aux?

Comment: I get `syscall.Getpid()` after fork. I print PID that I pass to `syscall.Kill()`. It seems I am unable to start web server in daemon also. I even tried to use unix sockets. It creates socket file but control is not working. But daemon is able to run subprocess that is able to start webserver. Is there something related to permissions that block daemonized process from listening. If I do not daemonize process then everyting works. (Signals, WebServers, Unix Sockets) It is very odd that I can't kill that process. It looks like it is dead and not working.

Comment: I now wonder: are you daemonizing in Go, using syscalls? This simply [won't work reliably](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=227) and you might expect all sorts of funny behaviour.

Comment: @kostix that is an answer! Please post your last comment as answer and  I will mark it as answer. How to daemonize in Go is another question and I will go with `nohup` right now. I used code inspired with https://gist.github.com/wofeiwo/3634357

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Daemonizing a Go process using syscalls [is not currently possible to do reliably](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=227) and that's why your sort-of-daemonized process was impossible to kill: it has been wedged (though I should admit it's weird why it did not die in response to sending `SIGKILL` which makes the kernel just destroy the process, no signal delivery is attempted).

To properly daemonize a Go process one is advised to use a wrapper process (such as [`daemon`](http://libslack.org/daemon/)) or run it under an an advanced substitute for the `init` superserver such as `systemd` or `upstart` or a standalone supervisor such as `runit`, `monit` and others—in which case the process has no braindead requirement to be a true Unix daemon and may behave like a normal process: does not perform double-`fork`+`setsid` trickery, does not mess with PID file management, is able to write to its regular I/O streams etc.